# List of instance methods of current class only

Tags: ruby

I have an instance `o` of class `O`. I'd like to know what `o` is capable of.

`o.methods` will give me many methods. So I usually do `o.methods - Object.instance_methods`. But that is not concise.

I want to do something like `o.methods - o.class.superclass.instance_methods`. That is, just the methods defined in `O` itself.

Is there some other way?

Comment: Does `o.methods(false)` work?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev No, that would not work, because the meaning of the `false` argument to `methods` is to list only singleton methods, ex. `'foo'.methods(false) # => []`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the method [`Module#instance_methods`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Module.html#method-i-instance_methods):

```
o.class.instance_methods(false)
```

**Warning** The documentation seems to be wrong, it says that:

> **With no argument**, or **with an argument that is false**, the instance
>   methods in mod are returned, otherwise the methods in mod and mod’s
>   superclasses are returned.

But actually the parameter by default is `true`:

```
String.instance_methods.size
# => 184
String.instance_methods(false).size
# => 130
```